# Dynatrace integration with Apache webserver

Tags: apache, dynatrace

I have an Apache webserver with PHP module where I display some information.  I'd like to be able to get some data from dynatrace and put the data in the webserver through some cronjob.  The problem is I have no clue on how to push data from dynatrace to a server. Is there any APIs for this or a different way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynatrace provides a REST Reporting interface where you can pull out any data from dynatrace that you can put on a dashboard and get it in something consumable such as CSV, XML, JSON, ... - here is the link to the public doc page on the reporting interface: https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/DOCDT61/Server-+and+Clientside+XML+Reporting

So - what you need to do is the following

## 1: Create a dashboard and put your charts on it that show the measures you are interested in, e.g: Apache Thread Count, CPU, Throughput, ...

## 2: Save that dashboard on your dynatrace server

## 3: Use the REST interface to query that data and put it into your external system

if you have more questions on this feel free to also post them on our own Dynatrace community forum: https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/DTFORUM/dynaTrace+Forums+Home

Andi

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I will be giving this a try and will let you know if this succeeds!